# How can update static files in node js app?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have nodejs app using express module, i had been changes some images inside public folder but when i checked from users side still on the old images and when clear browser cache i get on new images , is there a command to make this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Etag. If the content of the resource is not changed the server will not send it again. When it is, as in your case it will.

Looking at the express docs I see etag is an boolean option of the middleware function static.

express.static({etag: true})

Some background information about tags.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag